# How to drop and recreate indexes without growing the transaction log

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I wanted to change a field in a database table to be a calculated field rather than being populated using a trigger.

I am using Entity Framework database first so I added this sql to a migration to carry out the task:

```
EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseAnsweredQuestions] DROP COLUMN [CalculatedDueDate]
')

EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE dbo.BaseAnsweredQuestions ADD
    CalculatedDueDate  AS etc...')
```

This gave me a problem because a couple of indexes are dependent on this field. So I added drop sql for the index before the table changes with recreate sql after the changes.

When I ran the migration on my "staging" database I got an error:

> Transaction Log for database is full

And my application would not run at all. I ran a database backup and that appeared to clear the problem, however I want to run the migration on production. How can I prevent the transaction log overflow occurring?

Comment: From Microsoft: [Manage the Size of the Transaction Log File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/manage-the-size-of-the-transaction-log-file). - May be of some use. The article lists the following suggestions: Shrink log file size, Add or enlarge a log file, Optimize tempdb transatction log size, or Control transaction log file growth.

Comment: You could set the recovery model to simple during the migration but this would temporarily affect your ability to recover from a failure.